# Whole right area of wordpress admin dashboard not showing

Tags: errors, dashboard

Whole right area of Wordpress admin dashboard not showing... WP version is 2.7.1

What could be the reason? It was working before.

[image]

Comment: Please edit your title to be an actual question. A screenshot would also be helpful, as would any additional information you can provide.

Comment: *@metal-gear-solid*: Agree with @tnorthcutt. You are asking lots of support questions http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/32/metal-gear-solid#questions but not putting much effort into selecting an appropriate title nor into giving the details we might need to recognize your problem quickly. Please start making sure that when you ask a question you put enough effort into writing your question to help us answer and so we can tell it's important enough to you that we answer. If not we are going to down vote your questions and/or just delete them.

Answer (score 4):

First, try disabling all of your plugins, and see if that fixes it.  If it does, enable them one at a time until you are able to reproduce the error. That should tell you which plugin is causing the problem.

Additionally, I strongly suggest you upgrade to 3.0.1.

Comment: and if possible check for css being inserted via hooks in plugins or your themes functions.php

Comment: The problem is "plug-in dashboard" has also gone Now how to disable all plugin then test one by one.

Comment: I renamed `plugin` directory to `pluginx` , then checked but no effect. Dasboard is still blank.

Comment: @Tom J Nowell - will you explain, how?

Comment: Have you upgraded to wordpress 3.0? I would consider that this entire question should really be deleted if you have no intention of updating

Answer (score -1):

in Wordpress 3 they can be hidden, have you just hidden them?

I second the notion to upgrade!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does, if the answer is the user has hidden them.

Comment: Why not explain how to show the items in question? Make it more specific rather than vague.

Comment: Maybe it should be expanded, but it is still a valid answer.

Answer (score -3):

I found the same problem  and renaming the plugin and theme folder but not found sunccess but when i tried to resolve it the main problem was in screen.php which found in **/wp-admin/includes ->screen.php** i commented the following line like

_help_sidebar; ?>

Hope it will be heplfull :)

Comment: Downvote for formatting, spelling and the advice of hacking a core file...